# Minecraft 1.9 give a specific map

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to give myself a filled_map with data value `0`, i.e. the very first map I would have ever generated.

I have tried:

```
/give @p minecraft:filled_map:0
```

which outputs the error: `There is no such item with name minecraft:filled_map:0`.

I have also tried:

```
/give @p minecraft:filled_map 1 0
```

Which I'm assuming used to work in earlier versions of the game because of [this other question](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2085120-how-do-you-give-a-player-a-specific-map-using).

However, that command just gives me the next map in sequence (so if I am currently at the map with ID `#0358/16` it would give me the map with id `#0358/17`, *not* the `#0358/0` which I want.)

Please, I need to know how to fix this. Maybe there is an attribute I can set in the data tag? I.e.

```
/give @p minecraft:filled_map 1 0 {mapNumber:0}
```

But I do not know if such a thing exists.

Comment: The second one should have worked, but maybe the first map is 1, I'm not certain

Comment: I tried with `1` as well, same problem (it gives me the next map in sequence)

Comment: @Unionhawk I think the first map is 0 though

Answer (score 2):

Hah hah! I figured it out.

Turns out, I'd been messing around too much; this command is the one which works:

```
/give @p minecraft:filled_map 1 0
```

The problem is (was) I had deleted `map_0.dat` from my `data` folder; I had wanted to replace it with another image, so I thought I should delete it to re-generate it afresh, however the way I should have gone about it was just placing my custom map files into the folder before trying to generate them.