# Can I get filled in maps using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't mind cheating in my single player survival world. But I used kill all entities while filling a large chunk with air to get rid of the mobs. But I didn't know item frames are also entities. Why are item frames also entities? Minecraft can be so frustrating at times.

You see, I also had a 5x5 map wall on max zoom level (4/4).

**So, can I use command blocks to get my filled in maps back?**

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can! That is, as long as you know the *map number* of the map you want to remake (or can figure it out by experimenting).

```
/give [playername | @p] minecraft:filled_map [amount_of_maps] [map_number]
```

The key reason this may be possible for you is that you already had the map, since it doesn't appear to be currently possible to generate *new*, pre-filled maps.

Also backed up by the [Minecraft Wiki page on Maps](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#Trivia):

> A map created using `/give` can be any map by using the Map parameter to specify the map number desired. E.g. `/give [player] minecraft:filled_map{map:5}` gives the specified player map_5. If no data value is supplied it defaults to map_0. If map_0 has not ever been crafted, it is centered on x=0, z=0.

References:

- [This Arquade post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/266141/260049) by [@theonlygusti](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/137042/theonlygusti)
- [This Minecraft forum post](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/2085120-how-do-you-give-a-player-a-specific-map-using)

Answer (score 5):

The old way, `/filled map 1 0`, would give 1 map with `0` as the damage/NBT value (which was phased out in 1.13).

As data is now handled by NBT, the new correct command would be:

`/give @p filled_map{map:#}`

where, of course, the `#` is the number of the map you want.

Comment: The last paragraph of your answer is best suited as a comment and shouldn't be part of your answer. I can tell you that I've made that mistake several times when I was new here, and sometimes it didn't turn out very pretty. Hopefully my edit to remove that part will spare you from any possible bad experiences that might otherwise come your way.

Comment: um, sure thanks I guess

Answer (score -3):

See, THIS is why Minecraft needs an undo button at all times. Unfortunately, there's no way to get your maps back with commands. You'll have to make the maps again, sadly.

Comment: read above answer