# How to give myself maps that have already been created?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I created a bunch of maps, copied the map numbers and coordinates, then went to put them in item frames.  But then Minecraft crashed and when I came back the maps were gone.  When I try to create a new map it starts above the last map number I created, so it seems the game does know about them.

How can I give myself these maps by numbers so I don't have to go through all the work of re-creating them (not to mention duplicate map numbers for the same coordinates)?

I tried:

```
/give @s filled_map 1 0 {"map":170}
```

But I got the error

> Component 'map' was not an object.

I also tried upper-casing "Map" but got a similar error.

I also tried:

```
/give @s filled_map 1 170
```

But got the error:

> Invalid map data provided.

Comment: Perhaps can be answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376917/minecraft-can-i-get-filled-in-maps-using-command-blocks/376928).

Comment: @Skye-AT sadly that answer seems to only apply to the Java version