# How do I give myself a map with a specific map number?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use commands to give myself a map that correlates to like `map_1.dat` in the data folder, I've tried `/give @p minecraft:filled_map 1 0` and other things, but they don't seem to work in Minecraft 1.19.2. If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know. I can only find a similar question for 1.9, which doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get filled in maps using command blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376917/minecraft-can-i-get-filled-in-maps-using-command-blocks)